# Randomly select subsets from lists of sublists

Tags: python

I have **4** lists each contain  **3** sublists

```
L1 = [[sub11],[sub12],[sub13]]
L2 = [[sub21],[sub22],[sub23]]
L3 = [[sub31],[sub32],[sub33]]
L4 = [[sub41],[sub42],[sub43]]
```

I want to randomly select sublists from each  list to create a final **3** lists

for example the final **3** lists could look like

```
final1 = [[sub13],[sub21],[sub33],[sub42]]
final2 = [[sub12],[sub23],[sub31],[sub43]]
final3 = [[sub11],[sub22],[sub32],[sub41]]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try to come up with a start, I'm sure you have some idea. Then when you are stuck, ask a new question based on your own attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can randomize each one with `random.sample()` and then `zip()` the result:

```
>>> import random
>>> L1 = [['sub11'],['sub12'],['sub13']]
>>> L2 = [['sub21'],['sub22'],['sub23']]
>>> L3 = [['sub31'],['sub32'],['sub33']]
>>> L4 = [['sub41'],['sub42'],['sub43']]
>>> all_lists = [L1, L2, L3, L4]
>>> random_lists = map(list, list(zip(*(random.sample(item, len(item)) for item in all_lists))))
>>> for i in random_lists:
...     print(i)
...
[['sub13'], ['sub22'], ['sub33'], ['sub43']]
[['sub11'], ['sub23'], ['sub32'], ['sub42']]
[['sub12'], ['sub21'], ['sub31'], ['sub41']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L1 = [12, 13, 11]
>>> L2 = [22, 23, 21]
>>> L3 = [31, 32, 33]
>>> L4 = [41, 42, 43]
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> L = [L1, L2, L3, L4]
>>> for item in L:
...     shuffle(item)
... 
>>> F = zip(*L)
>>> final1, final2, final3 = F
>>> final1
(12, 22, 31, 41)
>>> final2
(13, 23, 32, 42)
>>> final3
(11, 21, 33, 43)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

L1 = [['sub11'],['sub12'],['sub13']]

L2 = [['sub21'],['sub22'],['sub23']]

L3 = [['sub31'],['sub32'],['sub33']]

L4 = [['sub41'],['sub42'],['sub43']]


final = []
for L in [L1, L2, L3, L4]:
    final.append(random.sample(L, 1)[0])

print final
```

Output:

```
[['sub11'], ['sub22'], ['sub31'], ['sub42']]
```

Repeat as many times as you need to build more random lists.